# How to automatically copy files from package to local directory via postinstall npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, installation, post-install

I want to automatically copy certain files from an `npm` package to user's **local directory** after running

`npm install my-package`

I can get them installed by declaring `"files"` inside `package.json`. The problem is --- the files are not put in the local directory. So I need to run `postinstall` script.

But now I don't know where the package is installed (maybe higher up the directory tree), so how can I reliably access the files and copy them to the local directory via the script?

(By **local directory** I mean --- from where I run `npm install my-package` **as user** consuming the package.)

UPDATE. It seems the `postinstall` script runs as `npm` owned process with home directory being `node_modules/my-package`, so I still don't know how to access user's home directory other than with naive `../../`.

Comment: An old question, I know but I'm facing a similar issue. Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: @danielv Yes, see https://github.com/dmitriz/min-karma

Comment: Thanks. I hoped that you found a more elegant solution for finding the base install directory other than `../../`.

Comment: @danielv Please let me know, should you ever come across a better solution.

Comment: @danielv Eventually, when even `npm` and `yarn` cannot agree on where to install, I have found this naive solution the most convenient and reliable one.

Comment: And if you, in the path of the current file, try to determine which is the last "node_modules" directory in the left? the previous directory is the local dir?

Answer (score 18):

Since npm 3.4 you can use the $INIT_CWD envar:
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/164504728630/v540-2017-08-22

> When running lifecycle scripts, INIT_CWD will now contain the original working directory that npm was executed from.

To fix you issue add to your postinstall script in package.json the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cp fileYouWantToCopy $INIT_CWD",
  },
```

Answer (score 16):

After a lot of searching I found this works cross platform

```
"scripts":
  "postinstall": "node ./post-install.js",
```

```
// post-install.js

/**
 * Script to run after npm install
 *
 * Copy selected files to user's directory
 */

const gentlyCopy = require('gently-copy')

const filesToCopy = ['.my-env-file', 'demo']

// User's local directory
const userPath = process.env.INIT_CWD

// Moving files to user's local directory
gentlyCopy(filesToCopy, userPath)
```

Answer (score 3):

`var cwd = require('path').resolve();`

> Note: If the arguments to resolve have zero-length strings then the current working directory will be used instead of them.

from https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: I am still confused which is `cwd` inside the `postinstall` script --- the local directory or where the installed files are sitting?

Comment: `cwd` is always where a program was executed from. If you need a path to current js file from a file itself there are `__filename` and `__dirname` variables available in every file.

Comment: I need path to the local directory, see last line in my question to define what I mean.

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not solve the problem. As the `node` scripts are executed from their package directory under `node_modules`, their `cwd` will never point to the local directory from where the user ran `npm install`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use shellscript/bash

-package.json

```
"scripts":
  "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh",
```

-postinstall.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# go to YOUR_NEEDED_DIRECTORY .e.g "dist" or $INIT_CWD/dist
cd YOUR_NEEDED_DIRECTORY

# copy each file/dir to user dir(~/)
for node in `ls`
do
  cp -R $node ~/$node
done
```

Don't forget to!

```
chmod +x postinstall.sh
```

Comment: It is not clear how this can help, I still need to know how to refer to the local directory in this code, so the same problem remains.

Comment: Because your script is running as part of a life cycle event, $INIT_CWD is available in this script.